# The dilemma of using both space-tab and tab

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

Now I have to learn some makefile. I only need to use the plain-old tab in this file. In other ones I want to happily keep my 4-space-tab. My current idea is to find a way/script so that I can toggle the next `<tab>` I press is space-tab or plain-old tab **and I don't want to make change to existing space-tabs/plain-old-tabs**. Is there a built-in option for this? If not could anyone shed some light on the script to achieve this?

Comment: not sure if this answers your question but vim already defaults to tabs in Makefile

Comment: @Mass: Oh, this solves my problem...

Comment: See `:setlocal`, `expandtab`, and `ftplugin`